# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: android, flutter, rest, dart, firebase-realtime-database

how to solve this problem?

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

```
  body: Stream Builder(


    stream: ref.child(SessionController().toString()).onValue,
    builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
      if (!snapshot.hasData){
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      else if(snapshot.hasData)
      {

       Map\<dynamic, dynamic\>  Data  = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;\`\`


        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: \[

            ReusbaleRow(title: 'address', value: Data\["Address"\] , iconData: Icons.ice_skating),
            ReusbaleRow(title: 'name', value: Data\["Name"\] , iconData: Icons.ice_skating),
            ReusbaleRow(title: 'Father Name', value: Data\["Father Name"\] , iconData: Icons.ice_skating),
            ReusbaleRow(title: 'CNIC No', value: Data\["CNIC No"\] , iconData: Icons.ice_skating),
            ReusbaleRow(title: 'District', value: Data\["District"\] , iconData: Icons.ice_skating)

          \],
        );
      }
      else
      {
        return const Center(child: Text("something went wrong"));
      }
    },
  ),
);

}
}
```

Comment: just add a if condition if(snapshot.data ==null){....} else{....}

Comment: sir its cant works they can give me the same error plx sir guide me how i solve this

Comment: did u print ur snapshot.data.snapshot, does it getting ur data's correcly ?

Comment: how can i print sir I don't understand can u write how i print that

Comment: if you don't mind did you give me your WhatsApp

Comment: no i cant print my data how i print that

Comment: print(snapshot.data.snapshot). don't worry about whatsApp we may do that

Comment: The getter 'snapshot' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: snapshot sir they give me this type of error when I put print(snapshot.data.snapshot) below this code

Comment: Map<dynamic, dynamic>  Data  = snapshot.data.snapshot.value; when i put this code print(snapshot.data.snapshot)

Comment: sir do you have any code about how to fetch profile data form realtimedatebase in flutter

Comment: Yeah this is a simple ToDo app. Homepages list are fetched in realtime. https://github.com/jbjason/task_app2/tree/main/lib

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the actual data type returned by `snapshot.data.snapshot.value` is `null` instead of `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. This can occur if the snapshot value is null or the data is not retrieved from the database correctly.

> You can add a null check before accessing the `snapshot.value`

```
    if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.snapshot.value == null) {
  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}

Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
```

Comment: its cant fetch data from database still loading when i put this ..its means cant read the database value